# C# Entity Framework Linq: Select Where If/Else

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

Is it possible to do a `.Where` with a series of nested `if` statements?

Here's what I'd like to do:

```
public class Repository {
    public async Task<IQueryable<Order>> orders (int? accountId, int? userId) {
        IQueryable<Order> orders;

        orders = _context.Orders
            .Where(o =>
            {
                int filterCount = 0;
                int filterCriteriaMet = 0;

                // if the accountId param is not null
                // increment the filter counter
                // and check if this order's accountId == param
                // if so, increment filterCriteriaMet counter
                if (accountId != null)
                {
                    filterCount++;

                    if (o.AccountId == accountId)
                    {
                        filterCriteriaMet++;
                    }
                }

                // if the userId param is not null
                // increment the filter counter
                // and check if this order's userId == param
                // if so, increment filterCriteriaMet counter
                if (userId != null)
                {
                    filterCount++;

                    if (o.UserId == userId) {
                        filterCriteriaMet++;
                    }
                }

                return filterCount == filterCriteriaMet;
            });

        return orders;
    }
}
```

but this gives me the following error:

> A lambda expression with a statement body cannot be converted to an expression tree

Comment: Yes.  Use format Where(a => (a == 123)? a : (a < 123) ? 0 : null)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure!

```
.Where(o => AccountId != null && o.AccountId == accountId || (UserId != null && o.UserId == UserId));
```

Comment: It's not "(if account id isn't null and it matches) OR (if user id isn't null and it matches)".
It would "(if account id is null or it matches) AND (if user id is null or it matches)
But that leads me in the right direction. Thanks

Comment: @JED strange, two nested ifs is an AND condition... well, glad to help anyway :)

Comment: I flipped the logic in my plain english version. you're right, the code reads "if account id IS null or it matches" but I wrote "if account id ISN'T null and it matches"

Comment: "Sure!"? Sure what? Your code isn't even close to the question's code , you should explain *why* the OP's code doesn't work and why yours will